# Duplicate CACHE and PRODUCT folders in /media

Tags: magento-1.9, product, catalog, cache, media

My `/media` folder size is getting a little out of hand. We have 8379 product records in the catalog. About 1000 of them are related to a customizer extension that we have, but the rest are Configurable products with a few Simple product attached. The catalog supports 5 stores across 5 domains and one shared cart.

I only upload images to the `Catalog/Search` products which are mostly Configurables. While trying to reduce the size of my `/media` folder, I found the [ImaClean](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-clean.html) extension a while ago and have toyed around with it. Enabling it again, I can see that there are 10,218 photos in the /media folder structure that aren't in the database.

With a little more digging, I saw that inside of my `/media/catalog/product` folder, there's another `/product` folder at nearly 5.5gb with it's own Cache (with a last modified date from 2 years ago). Is this normal, or should I delete it? Obviously a backup is ideal, but that's 5gb to backup somewhere else on my server - or and offline download. I don't remember creating this backup of images and it's content definitely looks reduced from what I'm seeing in the main `/product` folder.

How often should I be using the `Flush Catalog Images Cache` and `Flush Swatch Images Cache` buttons in the `Cache Management` page? Is there a good cronjob I can setup to do this?

We use CloudFlare so nearly all of our images are cached there and I have unlimited space with them.

I've debated decentralizing the /media folder onto an EC2 instance with AWS, but haven't found a clean way to do so, and the cost is worrysome with this many GB in just the `/media` alone.

This question is kind of ambiguous and open ended, but I'm looking for a real solution or suggestions on how to handle this situation.

[image]